# Deploy Click Once application for multiple servers

Tags: .net, winforms, clickonce

Good day folks,

I'm facing an issue here. I have a `winforms` app, and i'm struggling to deploy it.

The question here is that **I have 6 customers using the same app(this number tend to grow exponentially), most of them have their own server, and i don't want to change the update location on my click once publish settings every time I fix a bug.**

It would be really nice if I could deploy the app to a website and host it at the customer server. but again I have another issue, the hostname/domain should exist on the customers network.

A workaround is to edit the hosts file on each client machine (for this i could write a code within my app, so based on a config file it would rewrite the host file).

Another solution would be to implement a `CDN` on the customer server. I can't host my app on a online web site cause not all the client machines will have access to internet and would be out of date.

**The aim here is to build a single release and share through an ftp/cloud drive and than this release should be applied on any server without any additional change.**

Afterwords I would start controlling who should have which release without having to pay visits to the customers.

Comment: You should be able to setup ClickOnce over internet.web, refer here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/71baz9ah.aspx

Comment: I cant rely on a internet.web solution, view that I can't guarantee that all the client machines will have access to the web. If I could setup the server to download from Internet and the client to download from the server it would be great, but click once doesnt have any mean to setup 2 update locations for the same app/build.